# How to clone ('fork') your own personal GitHub repo to a new repo in a separate, new branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-remote, repo

I have a personal GitHub repo that I want to use as a starting point for new projects = other repos. This might be very easy for you, but I'm really a beginner, so I hope you can help me with this.

If I make changes to that scaffold repo, I need the option to merge/rebase them into the projects that stem from it. So a GitHub template repo will not do the trick.

I'm thinking of the following solution:

1. I have a template repo `username/template-repo`
2. Create an empty repo (manually or via `git clone`)
3. Create a new, empty branch `scaffold` (so we have `main` & `scaffold`)
4. Do a `git remote add`, so that the `scaffold` branch **contains exactly the contents** of the `template-repo`
5. Merge or rebase the local `scaffold` into the `main` branch
6. Work in the `main` branch and make commits.

If I want to get the new contents of the `template-repo`, I'd do sth like this:

1. Git pull `template-repo` into `scaffold` branch
2. Merge or rebase the `scaffold` branch with the `main` branch

I understand how Git works and I know what I need, but I just have difficulty setting this all up. I'd be very grateful if you could point out how I'd do this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't fork a repo into a branch. You seem to be confusing terms.

Comment: GitHub supports [templare repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/creating-a-template-repository).

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks for pointing that out. You are of course correct. What I meant was the functionality similar to forking and doing pull requests between them.

Comment: Thanks @dan1st, but a template repository is only a starting point for an other repo, and it doesn't allow you to merge or rebase changes from the template repo into the repos that stem from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, you are confusing terms. A repository/fork cannot be "compressed" into a single branch. However, I think your explanation is clear enough to give an answer to your question.

You can configure multiple remotes and this seems to be a good use case for this. It is somehow similar as setting an `upstream` repository when forking another repository. Instead of `upstream`, you basically have a `template` repository. Much of the same concepts apply since the fork should get changes from the upstream/template repository.

---

**The setup** could be something along these line:

1. When cloning, you give the remote repository the name *template* instead of *origin*:

   ```sh
   git clone -o template <repository> <directory>
   # example: git clone -o template https://.../username/template-repo.git project-dir
   ```
2. Add the remote repository for the project itself and push all branches:

   ```
   git remote add origin https://.../username/project-repo.git
   git push origin --all
   ```
3. Track the `main` branch on `origin` (instead of *template*):

   ```
   git push -u origin main
   ```
4. Set up a local branch that tracks a remote branch in the *template* repository (only needed when update-option B is used later):

   ```
   git branch --track scaffold template/main
   ```
5. Optionally, overwrite the push URL of the *template* repository so you don't accidentally push there from your project repository:

   ```
   git remote set-url --push template do-not-push
   ```

---

**Updating** the project repository with changes from the template repository **[Option A]**:

1. Fetch the template repository to have the latest changes:

   ```
   git fetch template
   ```
2. Merge the changes of `template/main` into the *current branch**:

   ```
   git merge template/master
   ```

   **Note that the current branch could be directly your project's `main` branch or another branch which will be used to test everything first (recommended) and then merge into `main` later on – maybe with a pull request.*

---

**Updating** the project repository with changes from the template repository **[Option B]**:

1. When you have set up a remote tracking-branch `scaffold` (see step 4 in the setup), you can check it out and pull the changes:

   ```
   git checkout scaffold
   git pull
   ```
2. Merge `scaffold` into the desired branch. This could be `main` or another branch where you first integrate and test the changes (recommended).

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks so much for this explanation! It certainly makes sense. I'll try it out and mark it as correct (hopefully) this afternoon.

Comment: Decided to quickly test if I can get it up and running, and it works, awesome! 